# C++ unused expression warning: swapping array elements

Tags: c++, arrays

I am using C++ to efficiently swap elements between arrays using a temporary variable, but I get the error: Expression result unused.

Here is how the warning arises:

```
for(i = 0; i < (n - 1); i++) {
          tmp = x[ind, i]
    x[ind, i] = x[ind, i + 1]
x[ind, i + 1] = tmp
}
```

The problem is with 'ind', which is a vector of random positive integers, being unused. All other variables are ints.

Comment: What do you think `x[ind, i]` does? Because it is equivalent (in your case) to `x[i]`

Comment: Please include a [MCVE].

Comment: "*Does an unused expression cause issues with program output in this context?*" No, because it is unused...

Comment: "to the non-programmer it may appear that something is wrong whenever a warning does appears." To the programmer it may appear that something is wrong when another programmer ignores warnings.

Comment: @bolov But other programmers ignore warnings all the time. I don't know how to cope with this life anymore...

Comment: What do you mean by "your target audience"?

Comment: And they are supposed to see your code and warnings how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is with `ind`, which is a vector of random positive integers, being unused. All other variables are ints.

It sounds like you need to use:

```
for(i = 0; i < (n - 1); i++) {
    tmp = x[ind[i]];
    x[ind[i] = x[ind[i + 1]];
    x[ind[i + 1]] = tmp
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`x[ind, i]` is equivalent to `ind; x[i]` which is equivalent to `x[i]` since `ind` has no side effects. The compiler warns that you didn't use the result of the expression `ind`.

> Does an unused expression cause issues with program output in this context?

Not as such. An unused expression usually means that the programmer made a mistake. Accessing `x[i]` when your intention was to access something else can potentially have issues with program output.

> I am uncertain how to suppress the warning

Best way is to not have any whose result is left unused. In this case you could replace `x[ind, i]` with `x[i]` (and the other expressions similarly) and the program would remain equivalent and there would not be a warning. However, before you do that, consider whether that was what you intended to do in the first place. I suspect that you did after all intend to use `ind` in one way or another.

Answer (score 2):

You probably meant to write `x[ind[i]]` based on naming conventions, because right now you're just using `operator ,()` and ignoring the value of `ind`.